# How to display month names in following sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I am under a situation that i have to write a code to print the name of all  months covered up in the given interval.
There will be 4 ways of displaying  those name of interval.

(1.) Yearly (1 cycles)

(2.) SemiAnnually (6 cycles)

(3.) Quarterly (3 cycles)

(4.) Monthly (12 cycles)

The user gives 3 inputs, one is start date and another is cycle. So the month name display must start from the startDate month which user selects and must end on the cycle he enters and the third input will be checkBoxSelecionStatus where he will enter "Monthly" (12), "Yearly" (1), "Quarterly" (3),"Semi-Annually"(6). So this checkBoxSelecionStatus  will decide the index-skip in for loop in `getMonthByDescription()` function

Now what has to  be the output :

(1) When user selects "Monthly" in checkBoxSelecionStatus and numOfCycles variable has 12 value and startDate is 3 (by startDate=3 means it started from 1st of march to next 12 cycles(numOfCycle), which is march of next year). then the output should be all 12 months which comes under this interval. so it's 
output is :

```
Mar
*****
Apr
*****
May
*****
Jun
*****
Jul
*****
Aug
*****
Sep
*****
Oct
*****
Nov
*****
Dec
*****
Jan
*****
Feb
*****
```

(2)Now when the user selects "SemiAnually" in cycle=12 then it must display the

```
Mar-Aug
*****
Sept-Feb
*****
```

(3) Now when the user selects "Quaterly" in cycle=12 , then it must display :

```
Mar-May
*****
Jun-Aug
*****
Sep-Nov
*****
Dec-Feb
*****
```

(4) Now when the user selects "Yearly" in 12 cycle then it must display :

```
Mar-Feb
*****
```

The user may not enter int startDate = 3; all the time. He may enter startDate = 1;(here the month display will start from 1st month, which is Jan) or he may enter any startDate, so code must work for all.

**Note:** Please note that the desired part is not wrong in any case. In case of quarterly i must have 3 because there are 4 quarters of "3" in a year (it's based on other calculations of my software)so when user selects "Quarter" then it must show  "`jan-mar" (if start date is first jan) then apr-jun then jul-sep then oct-dec`. Similarly for semi-annually `jan-jun then jul-dec`

Comment: I think the desired output for `"Quaterly"` is wrong.  Quarterly is 4 times per year but you have 7 or 8 depending on what the last one represents

Comment: I think the desired output for `"SemiAnually"` is wrong, too. In my opinion, it should be just "March" and "September". You should explain how these desired outputs are formed.

Comment: @thanks all please see the Notes: part of my code to clear your doubt.

Comment: I had posted an answer, but reviewing your notes, my solution was not giving the "month before first" as you requested. I am still puzzled how you handle this. It is counter intuitive to any software I have seen/written that use dates for reporting.

Comment: So it seems you want to output the start and end month of each interval. Then why is September not included after August in the SemiAnnually example?

Comment: @LucMorin yaah i have seen your solution and run it. Thats true that it do not give me the "month before first". But i have to display  the requested way only . Thats why i was obliged to ask you experienced guys, if it was such simple i could have done it , there was no need to trobule you guys :)

Comment: Well, if that's the requirement, then we have to do with it. Could you please edit your question and clearly specify that you must output the beginning and ending month for each interval? Then it becomes clearer what you want.

Comment: @NicoSchertler yaah you are right. My fault..just edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @dear helpers, I have edited the output requested in my question yo make you more clear. please see it.

Comment: @struggling please take a look at my Linq version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your adapted code. It just advances the current interval by the specified interval length. Nothing special:

```
private static string[] getMonthByDescription(int startMonth, int startYear, int numcycle)
{
    startMonth -= 1; //zero-based index

    int intervalLength = 0;
    switch (checkBoxSelecionStatus)
    {
        case "Monthly": intervalLength = 1; break;
        case "Quarterly": intervalLength = 3; break;
        case "SemiAnually": intervalLength = 6; break;
        case "Yearly": intervalLength = 12; break;
    }
    if (intervalLength == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    int intervals = numcycle / intervalLength;
    string[] arrOfMonthName = new string[intervals];

    for(int i = 0; i < intervals; ++i)
    {
        if (intervalLength > 1)
        {
            var intervalEnd = startMonth + intervalLength - 1;
            var intervalEndYear = startYear;
            if (intervalEnd >= 12)
            {
                intervalEnd -= 12;
                ++intervalEndYear;
            }
            arrOfMonthName[i] = monthNames[startMonth] + " " + startYear + " - " + monthNames[intervalEnd] + " " + intervalEndYear;
        }
        else
            arrOfMonthName[i] = monthNames[startMonth] + " " + startYear;
        startMonth += intervalLength; //go to the next interval
        if (startMonth >= 12)
        {
            startMonth -= 12;
            ++startYear;
        }
    }

    return arrOfMonthName;
}
```

Comment: Fast and perfect :) it would me much great of you if you please  let me know the way to display like : mar,2016-aug2016  then sep,2016-feb,2017 (In case if startDate is 3, numCycle=12 and checkBoxSelecionStatus="SemiAnually") i mean with year.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might prefer a different approach, here's my "Linqified" version:

```
void Main()
{
    int period = 1;
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);
    var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
        .Select((i, m) => new { index = i, Month = start.AddMonths(m).ToString("MMMM-yyyy")})
        .GroupBy(o => (o.index) / period);

    foreach (var grp in result)
    {
        if (grp.Count() == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grp.First().Month);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", grp.First().Month, grp.Last().Month));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("****");
    }

}
```

Simply change the `period` variable to reflect how many months in a period you need. The special case is when period==1, then the output is not a range, but single months.

EDIT: Added year